# Recovering missing photos from older library

Tags: photos

Since Catalina Update, a lot of pictures are missing from Photos.
I have read about this issue that may be [due to the library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204887) being used, however I would like to know if is there a way to move the photo left in an older library without loosing those in the current one. I have 4 devices synchronising photos to Icloud and don't want to mess everything!

Comment: Big mistake. syncing photos across devices, means if you delete a photo anywhere; the photo is deleted every where.  To archive photos, export them out of photos app.  Have three backups.  one should be in a bank vault or online. Apple provides syncing not backup.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I wasn't asking about the best backup strategy.. I use time machine for now. Got back missing pictures for an older backup